# cant access multiple data schema for the spring boot application and an alternate of @Primary

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

i am  getting an issue while connecting with two different schema(MySQL) in spring boot and i shouldn't use @primary for the declaration and i need an alteration instead of @primary .

```
#first db
spring.datasource.url = [url]
spring.datasource.username = [username]
spring.datasource.password = [password]
spring.datasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#second db ...
spring.secondDatasource.url = [url]
spring.secondDatasource.username = [username]
spring.secondDatasource.password = [password]
spring.secondDatasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver


@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

here I'm not allowed to use @Primary in this......

Comment: What happens when you simply remove the @Primary annotation? I guess the default auto configuration of jdbc/jpa wouldnt work. But you should be able to configure them.